# Dipole Moment (spherical/arbitrary charge density)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, charge, dipole-moment

I'm new here. I got to this website while searching for links to fill my gaps on some topics. I have found some amazing posts for many different topics. Just amazing.

Anyway, I'm currently dealing with an exercise concerning dipole moments where I'm just stuck.

Here's the problem:

> a) There's a radially symmetric charge density $\rho(r)$ centered around the origin. Determine the dipolemoment of that charge density.
>
> b) Let $\rho(r)$ be an arbitrary charge density now. Under what circumstances does the dipole moment of the displaced charge density  $\rho '(\vec{r}) = \rho (\vec{r}-\vec{b})$ differ from the one not displaced at all.

Alright, here's what I got so far:

a) I was thinking of looking at the charge density as some spherical 'electron cloud' and that the charge density is proportional to the distance from the centre out to a distance, let's say R. That is

$\rho(r)=kr$

My next step was to find the total charge, meaning I solved the integral:

$q = 4\pi \int_0^R kr\cdot r^2 dr = \pi k R^4$.

Meaning, that the charge density can be expressed as

$\rho (r)=\frac{q}{\pi R^4}r$, right?

And here's where I'm stuck. To determine the dipole moment there has to be a field applied to the electron cloud, so that the electron cloud and the nucleus are separated by a distance, let's say **d**, correct?

Rereading the chapter in my workbook I thought of applying Gauss's Law somehow, but I don't know if that's the right way to go. But for completene's sake I'm going to write that anyway (better than nothing):

$4\pi d^2 E =\frac{4\pi}{\epsilon_0}\int_0^d \frac{q}{\pi R^4}r\cdot r^2 dr=\frac{qd^4}{\epsilon_0 R^4}$.

So I was guessing that the dipole moment would then simply be:

$p =qd =R^2\sqrt{4\pi \epsilon_0 q E}$. Would be cool if my results for a) are correct.

b) I basically have no idea about this part. I don't even know how to start.

I hope some can help me out here.

Comment: I think that there are some problems with your question. You ask in part (a) about the dipole moment of a symmetric charge distribution, but then when you present your own analysis you start start talking about not just a dipole moment but about an induced dipole moment due to an applied field. There was no mention of an applied electric field in the question. Also, where did the charge of a "nucleus" come in? There was no mention of a "nucleus" or implication that the charge density represented an electron cloud in your original question.

Comment: @SamuelWeir You're right. But how is that a dipole then?

Comment: - That's right. A radially symmetric charge distribution doesn't have a dipole moment. It seems that the answer is zero. But that sounds a bit too easy and trivial. Are you sure you copied the entire question?

Comment: @SamuelWeir
Yeah, I did. So, I guess this was just a trick question then and is just zero. So I guess my answer then applies to b) instead?

Comment: Problem is that - unless I missed something - that part (b) appears to be trivial, too. The transformation of the charge density being presented is a simple spatial translation, so the magnitude and orientation of whatever dipole moment that the charge distribution has should be unchanged.